# Trying to append text to a property inside a loop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have an array of struct objects.  These objects have a property for title (which is a String), and a property for location (of type Location).

What I would like to is append a double value for distance derived from the location property and the distance function with another, existing Location object, to the title property.  Here is the code I am working with:

```
self.myList.map({$0.title.append("\($0.location.distance(from: location!)/1000)")})
```

The problem here is that the map function returns a new array, however, I need to make the change to the existing array, since I'm using this array as the datasource for my UITableView.  The other problem is that despite me making the title property a var, I am always told the following error message:

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: '$0' is immutable.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: reassign the result back to `self.myList`

Comment: @Alexander How would I do that?

Comment: `self.myList = self.myList.map({$0.title.append($0.location.distance(from: myLocation!)/1000)})`

Comment: Wait, why are you calling `append` within `map`? `append` returns nothing (`Void`)

Comment: I'm trying to add a String to the existing String property.

Comment: I've corrected the code to show what it is I'm trying to do more accurately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152289/discussion-between-alexander-and-syedfa).

Comment: Why you instead of modify your object title don´t add this location thing in your cellForRow and keep your object title unchanged, this also make an improvement because your location will be updated @syedfa

Comment: @ReinierMelian I can't because the title isn't being assigned to the cell in that method.  The cell calls its configure method which accepts a viewModel object, and there, in that method the cell's label gets assigned the title property.

Comment: but you can in your cell method do that, think about it i would do this by that way i think is better approach @syedfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the array like this:

```
for (i, _) in myList.enumerated() {
    myList[i].title.append("\(myList[i].location.distance(from: location) / 1000)")
}
```

Comment: For some weird reason, your original answer worked, but this one does not.  The text for some reason is not being appended to the title property.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a temporary **mutable** variable:

```
myList = myList.map { (myStruct: MyStruct) -> MyStruct in
    var mutableStruct = myStruct
    mutableStruct.title.append("\(element.location.distance(from: location) / 1000)")
    return mutableStruct
}
```